# button covered transparent image not work

Tags: html, css

please, how activate button `hero_btn_id` covered transparent image `top_image_id`? or more precisely, how disable layer `top_image_id`? :)

```html
<div id="back_image_id">
   <a id="hero_btn_id" href="#"></a>
</div>
<div id="top_image_id"></div>
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/3ebdb/

Complete example https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55504690/examples/web/index.html

Comment: Please be specific what you want to do??

Comment: Can I ask why you have the transparent image over the top? You either need to hide the image or change the z-index level of the image and the button

Comment: Duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Comment: thanks, i work in AS3. HTML/CSS is for my very different language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In <`a>` tag I have added `z-index:1` added int the code. Here is the code

http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/3ebdb/11/

Comment: thanks, but i not understand why not work in html https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55504690/examples/web/index.html

Comment: no egg not clickable. only button `hero_btn_id` is clickable

Comment: Solution is for all covered div implement css `pointer-events:none;`

Comment: @Abedron you should hit the green check button..so other users can get benefits.